# How to do a RegEx to select all the specific characters of each line starting with a specific string

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I'm really not good at regular expression, so I'm sorry if this question seems too simple...

In order to make a project written in C that uses Windows backslashes in the relative paths of file inclusions compatible with Unix standards, I would like to be able to replace all of them with a normal slash. Thus,

```
#include <abc\def\ghi>
#include <jkl\mno\pqr>
#define  NEWLINE "\n"
```

would become

```
#include <abc/def/ghi>
#include <jkl/mno/pqr>
#define  NEWLINE "\n"
```

To do this, Visual Studio Code has the regular expression search functionality. So I tried to find a way to express the backslash selection via a RegEx, but I can't do it. My track is the following:

```
^(#include(Do something here to match '\')*)$
```

But I don't know how to make the backslash selection...

What would be the way to write such a regular expression?

Comment: `^#include.*\\.*$` should do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find

```
^(#include [^\\]+)\\(.*)$
```

Replace

```
$1/$2
```

Apply as often as needed.

Example: https://regex101.com/r/t48Kn4/1

Comment: You could simplify this to `^(#include [^\\]+)\\ `, replacing the match with `$1/` each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

In a Find in a file (will not work across multiple files because of the non-fixed length lookbehind, but works fine in a find within a file):

`(?<=^#include.*)(\\)`  it gets all `\` in a `#include` line

Replace all such `\` with `/`

`/`

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace matches of the following regular expression with a forward slash.

```
(?<=^#include +<[^>\\]+(?:\\[^>\\]+)*)\\(?=[^<]+>)
```

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5e%23include+%2b%3c%5b%5e%3e%5c%5c%5d%2b%28%3f%3a%5c%5c%5b%5e%3e%5c%5c%5d%2b%29*%29%5c%5c%28%3f%3d%5b%5e%3c%5d%2b%3e%29&i=%23include+%3cabc%5cdef%5cghi%3e%0d%0a%23include+%3cjkl%5cmno%5cpqr%3e%0d%0a%23define++NEWLINE+%22%5cn%22&r=%2f&o=m) (Click on "Context" to see replacements.)

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?<=             : begin positive lookbehind
  ^              : assert beginning of string
  #include +<    : match '#include', 1+ spaces, '<'
  [^>\\]+        : match 1+ chars other than '>' and '\'  
  (?:\\[^>\\]+)  : match '\' followed by 1+ chars other than '>' and '\'
                   in a non-capture group 
  *              : executed the above non-capture group 0+ times
)                : end positive lookbehind
\\               : match '\'
(?=[^<]+>)       : positive lookahead asserts that match is followed by 1+
                 : chars other than '<' followed by '>'
```

Note that the positive lookbehind is *variable length*. .NET's regex engine is one of the few that that support variable-length lookarounds, one of its strengths.